# Make [toc] a synonym of [tableofcontents]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[toc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toc) is an appreviations for [tableofcontents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableofcontents) and [tableofcontents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableofcontents) is the most common related tag for [toc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toc). I suggest we make these two tags synonyms with [tableofcontents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableofcontents) as the master tag.

Comment: on what StackExchange?

Comment: @djechlin On StackOverflow. (I tagged the questions as such and clicking the tags is the question leads there.)

Comment: was confused since when I clicked it defaulted to the "featured" tab which was blank. But I see now.

Comment: I wouldn't accept an answer which isn't implemented on a synonym-request. But that's just me...

Comment: I am not a native english speaker but I think you question, can be interpreted wrongly. Maybe add a comma or a full stop before "and".

Comment: Looks like ToC is being used for Theory of Computation in many places. That needs to be taken care of before we synonymize the tags.

Comment: Went through the posts, seems like there were 9 related to computation theory (I remember seeing more, but I guess someone has retagged it already). Atleast that issue is over now.

Comment: checked the remaining ones, they were all about table of contents. Syn'd now

Answer (score 8):

Given there aren't that many questions using either, I think the better option would be to just remove the [toc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toc) tag and [tableofcontents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableofcontents) from all questions, and replace with a new [table-of-contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) tag.  The dashes for spaces convention is far easier to read and is more commonly accepted around the site.

Once that is done, [toc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toc) and [tableofcontents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableofcontents) will just fade into the sunset.  If either gets recreated, then it might be the appropriate time to discuss synonymizing the tags.

---

All this being said, I completely forgot that us mere mortals can't create [table-of-contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/table-of-contents) since [tableofcontents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableofcontents) already exists.  The alternative would be to just use [tableofcontents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tableofcontents) then have a moderator rename the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'm somewhat opposed to this, since

- it isn't that common,
- use of "toc" to mean "table of contents" isn't overwhelming,
- I don't think it's a particularly meaningful acronym - certainly impossible to tell from the acronym alone unless you already are in the table-of-contents community

My third point is most dubious but I think it applies here, since you could say similar things about, say, [http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http) or [wysiwyg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wysiwyg). There's a difference between "everyone in my field calls it this and knows what it means," and "it made enough sense and was easier to type," and this is the former.